# SQL Server distributed transaction locks entire database

Tags: sql-server, transactions, deadlock

I'm running a distributed transaction from Server A > DB_A to a linked Server B > DB_B. The transaction creates tables and inserts rows on the linked Server B > DB_B.

I've noticed that when the transaction is running (it runs every hour via a SQL Server Agent job), if I try to access Server B > DB_B and open the tables list, I receive the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMidL.png).

My understanding of transactions was that I wouldn't be able to access the table being worked on itself, but I WOULD be able to access other database tables. Why is this happening? Are there alternatives when writing to a linked server?

Comment: Why are you regularly creating tables inside of a transaction like this? This sounds like there might a better way to tackle whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: Linked servers and transactions are a pain. I would set up staging databases and run SSIS jobs between the servers. Hell even replication to server b then do some transformation is easier. About why the DB gets locked. Its called lock escalation. It goes something like this(queue the bones song) row lock,  page lock,   table lock, db lock. To keep the locking more lightweight SQL can decide to move a row lock to page lock etc. Some code would help too....

Comment: Lock escalation, interesting. Didn't know about that. What if I did the same process as above but did the ETL to a staging database (Server B > DB_C), then copied the table over to DB_B. Would I run into any lock escalation there?